# Sort rows according to "primary key" and "auto_increment" column in phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I want that phpmyadmin returned ascended sorted  rows, according to column, with has `primary key` and `auto_increment`  (for example `id`).

somethimes My phpmyadmin returns disordered rows. there is some option for sorting rows? This is just more readable.

Comment: By default sorting is done with primary key column in ascending order. if you want to sort with custom columns then use `ORDER BY col_name DESC or ASC`

Comment: `By default sorting is done with primary key column in ascending order`. Not works always, I am talking about phpmyadmin

Answer (score 1):

By default, phpMyAdmin does not perform any kind of sort, and just shows the rows as they are stored in the database. Sometimes rows get inserted "out of order", but you can fix this:

- navigate to the table in question
- click 'operations'
- at the top left, under "Alter table order by", select your key and your order, and click 'go'

This is an ongoing maintenance thing that you will need to do from time to time, but it should solve your issue for the most part.

Comment: Thank you, this helped organize my database.

Answer (score 1):

In phpMyAdmin 4.5.0, maybe in earlier versions too, you can set the [$cfg['TablePrimaryKeyOrder']](http://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_TablePrimaryKeyOrder) config like so:

```
$cfg['TablePrimaryKeyOrder'] = 'DESC'
```

> This defines the default sort order for the tables, having a primary key, when there is no sort order defines externally. Acceptable values : [‘NONE’, ‘ASC’, ‘DESC’]

This sets the default sort if the table has a primary key and that no other sort has been applied to it.